# Accessing IRQ description array within a module and displaying action names

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, irq

I am programming a kernel module in C which is struggling to access IRQ description array elements and to display all action names of these elements.

At the beginning, I thought that this irq_desc array is sonething like a macro but after compiling i understood it is not. Then I used for_each_irq_desc(irq, desc) function. but this time it returned a warning:

WARNING: "irq_to_desc" [/home/samet/Masaüstü/Assignment3/Ass-1.ko] undefined!

and after this warning, i tried to insmod the module into kernel this time an error message popped:

insmod: error inserting './Ass-1.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module

after this i included all header files that i think relevant to this process, but nothing changed.

since it is very short i am attaching the code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kernel.h>   
#include <linux/init.h>     
#include <linux/sched.h>    
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <linux/irqdesc.h>
#include <linux/irqnr.h>

struct task_struct* p;
struct irq_desc* irqElement;
int irq, desc;

static int __init ass_1_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Ass-1 module is starting...\n");

    for_each_process(p){printk("%d\t%s\n", p->pid, p->comm);}

    for_each_irq_desc(irq, irqElement){printk("%p\n", irqElement);}

    return 0;
}

static void __exit ass_1_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Ass-1 module is finishing...\n");
}

module_init(ass_1_init);
module_exit(ass_1_exit);
```

Comment: What kernel version are you using?

Comment: I refer you to question 8251226. 'I don't believe you can use irq_to_desc() in a module.'

Comment: @KristofProvost 2.6.37.6

Comment: @hellork I believe that my answer is at your reference. however, although i have been reading about it for hours, i could not implement the EXPORT_SYMBOL(bla bla bla) part because they mention two different irq_to_desc functions loacted different places. If you can understand what they are talking about could you demonstrate it on a sample code for me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you really overestimate my abilities. This is my first hello world kernel module. But if anything, experience has taught me that the programmer is king. If you want something, define it.

The kernel headers don't want to expose irq's to modules, that's clear, so I'll bet this won't be supported and this may be generally a bad idea. But we don't care about that. We're hackers!

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>     
#include <linux/sched.h>    
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <linux/irqnr.h>
#include <linux/irqdesc.h>

#define irq_to_desc(irq)        (&irq_desc[irq])
#define nr_irqs NR_IRQS
struct irq_desc irq_desc[NR_IRQS];

struct irq_desc *irqElement;
int irq;
int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "I HAZ MODULE\n");
    for_each_irq_desc(irq, irqElement){printk("%p\n", irqElement);}
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "BAI MODULE!!!1\n");
}
```

Comment: while that solves the problem of the undefined symbol, you will print the contents of your own `struct irq_desc`, not the one used in the kernel; probably not what you want.