# Why kernel headers don't want to expose irq's to modules?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am just going through below thread which says kernel headers don't want to expose irq's to modules.

[Accessing IRQ description array within a module and displaying action names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058594/accessing-irq-description-array-within-a-module-and-displaying-action-names)

but I'm not sure why is it so?

Also,I see some of drivers which doesn't make use of irq's ,does it mean these devices are not interuppt driven?

One of such driver is for lm73 sensors linux/drivers/hwmon/lm73.c which is mostly bind to i2c bus and is again a module.

So,how it all happen,how device choose not to be interrupt driven?

Comment: lm73 just plugs on top of the i2c subsystem, and the i2c driver(of which there are many different variants) is most likely interrupt driven.

Comment: @nos But there should some way for device to interrupt its bus also.is not it the case?

Comment: Perhaps. It depends on the sub system. If you're writing a module that sits on top of an i2c layer, you would rather call functions that the i2c layer has defined. And, if needed, that layer will take care of handing the bus, whether that needs an interrupt or not. That way you're not tied to any particular i2c chip. This is the case for the lm73 module, it is a driver for a sensor at the remote end of an i2c bus, it doesn't need to know how the local end of the i2c bus works as long as it can send messages to the other end.

Comment: Thanks @nos for making this valuable comments . It would be really helpful if you can add it as answer and pictorial view on lm73 like drivers communicate with i2c bus from remote end.

Comment: ok @nos, not a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing IRQ description array within a module and displaying action names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058594/accessing-irq-description-array-within-a-module-and-displaying-action-names)

Comment: @artlessnoise ,I just wanted to bring in attention of ARM guys on this question.If you feel this question doesn't fit for ARM,I am removing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IRQ` numbers in a module.  The question has two concepts; one is an [*IRQ descripton*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/irqdesc.h), which is what the Linux kernel uses to manage interrupts.

The `IRQ` number itself is used in any module with `request_threaded_irq()` and functions like it.  It is typical for a driver to be passed the `IRQ` number either through platform_data or a device tree.

You **may not** use the IRQ descriptions in a module (and I don't know why you would want to).  More correctly, converting from an `IRQ` number to an IRQ description in a module is not allowed.  Typically the *description* is just a large array indexed by the IRQ number, so the `irq_to_desc()` is a macro in some cases and it is never exported.

Comment: Thanks @artlessnoise and just gone through answer.I have a doubt here ,I saw in most of module have in my environment uses request_threaded_irq() instead of request_irq().is it some particular reason for the same?

Comment: Just, `request_threaded_irq()` is the newer version, allowing a quick first part followed by a 2nd 'threaded' portion.  The original `request_irq()` is just passing `NULL` for the *thread*.